# Не могу открыть результирующую картинку. Я ее записую в функции get_image(все происходит без ошибок, но почему то она не декодируется)

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
    BASE_URL = 'https://pixabay.com/api/'
    API_KEY = '16480353-7dbad8920b220c290462d5818'
    PER_PAGE = 3
    counter = 0

    def __init__(self, titles, signal):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.titles = titles
        self.signal = signal

    def get_image(self, title):
        response = requests.get(f'{GetImagesThread.BASE_URL}?key={GetImagesThread.API_KEY}&q={title}&per_page={GetImagesThread.PER_PAGE}')
        if response.status_code == 200:
            url = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))['hits'][0]['previewURL']
            print(url)
            image_response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
            print(image_response.content)
            if image_response.status_code == 200:
                photo_label = QLabel()
                with open(f"./temp/img{GetImagesThread.counter}.{url[-3:]}", 'wb') as f:
                    image_response.raw.decode_content = True
                    shutil.copyfileobj(image_response.raw, f)
                pixmap = QPixmap(f"./temp/img{GetImagesThread.counter}.{url[-3:]}")
                photo_label.setPixmap(pixmap)
                GetImagesThread.counter += 1
                return photo_label

    def run(self):
        for title in self.titles:
            image = self.get_image(title)
            try:
                self.signal.emit(image)
            except Exception as err:
                print(err)


class Window(QMainWindow):
    add_image = pyqtSignal(QLabel)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title = 'Pixabay'
        self.init_window()
        self.init_ui()
        self.show()

    def init_window(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(150, 150, 600, 400)

    def init_ui(self):
        root_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        input_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.images_layout = QVBoxLayout()
        input_layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignTop)
        self.titles_input = QLineEdit()
        self.titles_input.setPlaceholderText('Enter the titles')
        input_layout.addWidget(self.titles_input)
        get_images_button = QPushButton('Get images')
        get_images_button.clicked.connect(self.get_images)
        input_layout.addWidget(get_images_button)
        root_layout.addLayout(input_layout)
        self.loader = QProgressBar()
        root_layout.addWidget(self.loader)
        root_layout.addLayout(self.images_layout)
        root_widget = QWidget()
        root_widget.setLayout(root_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(root_widget)

    def get_images(self):
        titles_list = str(self.titles_input.text()).split(',')
        self.loader.setMaximum(len(titles_list))
        self.loader.setValue(0)
        self.thread = GetImagesThread(titles_list, self.add_image)
        self.add_image.connect(self.add_image_label)
        self.thread.start()

    def add_image_label(self, image_label):
        self.loader.setValue(self.loader.value() + 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я проверил Ваш код, благо в нём есть API ключ.

Файл картинки создаётся с нулевым размером.

вы можете использовать

```
if image_response.status_code == 200:
    with open(f'img{counter}.{url[-3:]}', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(image_response.content)
```

для сохранения картинки, вместо `shutil.copyfileobj(image_response.raw, f)`

Comment: спасибо, теперь картинки полноценно подгружаются